# Link to the next and previous page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, navigation

I have a pages with the links looks like this:

- site.com/news/2015-01-12-**8**
- site.com/news/2015-01-18-**9**
- site.com/news/2015-02-02-**10**
- site.com/news/2015-02-17-**11**

I need to change the last digit. For example...

Now I am on this page:

*site.com/news/2015-02-02-**9***

So my next page link should be *site.com/news/2015-02-02-**10***

And my previous page link should be *site.com/news/2015-02-02-**8***

I want to make the page which will look like this

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23508679/site-scr.png

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes. I have such script and it works - http://jsfiddle.net/keduz913/, but I have a problems with it. Some links have such view - site.com/news/2015-01-9 I get a broken link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can store the current index of the image. You can extract the last digit using regular expression.

JS code to extract last digits using image link :

```
var currentIndex = parseInt("site.com/news/2015-01-12-8".match(/(\d+)$/g)[0]);
```

and to get the previous and next link :

```
var currentImageLink = "site.com/news/2015-01-12-8" // For example;
var nextPageLink = "site.com/news/2015-01-12-8".replace(/\d+$/g, currentIndex+1);
var previousPageLink = "site.com/news/2015-01-12-8".replace(/\d+$/g, currentIndex-1);
```

Once you get the next and previous link, set the same to the previous and next anchor link.

Hope it helps.